# Nested pure function argument as table

Tags: pure-function, iteration

I made a nested pure function

```
Nest[(x^2)/ ((2x+1) + #)&, x,n]
```

I would like that for each iteration the value of x increment of 1, to have something like

$$\frac{1^2}{\frac{3 + 2^2}{5 + ...}}$$

I'm wondering if this is possible?

Comment: What about `Fold[#2^2/((2*#2+1)+#1)&,x,Range[5]//Reverse]`?

Comment: Or include `HoldForm`, i.e., `Fold[HoldForm[#2^2]/((2*#2 + 1) + #1) &, x, Range[5, 1, -1]]`

Comment: You guys are awesome, Thanks
I didn't know Fold works like Nest.

Comment: Hi. Here is a way using Nest  : `a = 5 + 1; Nest[(a -= 1 ; a^2/((2*a + 1) + #)) &, x, a - 1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html).

```
RecurrenceTable[
 {
  f[x] == (x^2)/((2 x + 1) + f[x - 1])
  , f[1] == 1/(1 + 3)
  }
 , f
 , {x, 3}]
```

> ```
> {1/4, 16/21, 189/163}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to implement this as a recursion:

```
f[x_] := f[x] = (x^2)/((2 x + 1) + f[x - 1]);
f[1] = 1/4;
```

Now to get the first 10 values:

```
f/@ Range[10]
```